# JSDoc commentsOnly plugin and line numbers

Tags: jsdoc3

I am using the commentsOnly plugin with JSDoc and I think it is working as it is supposed to, but I am  hoping for different behavior. When the line number is generated for the link back into the code it is providing the line number of the comment from the comments only generated file. This makes the generated links of no value as the document user will want link to the comment in the source file, not the comments only file (which is not even available as far as I can tell).

Does anyone know of a way to have the line number reported be the first line of the comment in the source file.

Thanks-
Matt